# Find an unbiased estimator with lower variance than given

Tags: statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent observations from a distribution $F$ with
$V ar(X_i) = σ^2 > 0$ and $0 < V ar(X_i^2 ) < ∞$. Prove that $T_1 = X_1^2
 − X_1X_2$
is unbiased for $σ^2$. Find another unbiased estimator for $σ^2$  having variance
strictly less than that of $T_1.$

first part i could prove but second part not being able to find a complete sufficient statistic on which i will calculate umvue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- You are not being asked for the *lowest* variance unbiased estimator, just a *lower* variance unbiased estimator
- Can you show $T_2=X_2^2 − X_1X_2$ has the same distribution as $T_1$?
- Some suitable combination of $T_1$ and $T_2$ might still be unbiased but have a lower variance

Comment: how to show T1 and T2 have same distribution

Comment: @DebarghyaMukherjee A symmetry/exchangeability argument may be enough

Comment: Yes got it thanks